# Emacs align-regexp command does not prompt group select for regexp pattern

Tags: emacs, prompt, text-alignment

I follow the steps which is on this article about command `align-regexp` to sort region text: http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/emacs_align_and_sort.html

I select the same sample with in upper example with region select.
And I executed `[C-u M-x align-regexp RET .* \([0-9,]+\).* RET]` on the select region, but did not get interactive group select prompt. Why?

EDIT:
My Emacs version:
24.3.50.1
System:
Ubuntu Linux 14.02 (x86_64)

Comment: Which version of Emacs are you using? `M-x emacs-version`

Comment: @phils My Emacs version is: 24.3.50.1

Comment: As that's not a release version (and without a date, it covers a very large set of possible source code versions), it's *possible* there's a bug in your version. It seems an unlikely one, though. Can you run `emacs -Q` and try the command again, and detail exactly which prompts you get?

Comment: Do you get prompted for *anything* other than the pattern? If not, make sure you're including the prefix argument `C-u`.

Comment: @phils `emacs -Q` can work.
@Chris I'm sure I select the text, and incluing the prefix argument `C-u`.
Seems problem here. I will debug it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Helm config init setup caused this problem.

Here is the reason

`(global-set-key (kbd "M-x") 'helm-M-x) ; conflict with {[C-u M-x align-regexp] on select region text.}`